# Creating an array of an object type defined in a com interface

Tags: c#, vba, com

I'm building a COM interface written in C# to be used in a VBA environment (Sax Basic).
I have a class defined in the COM application and I want to declare an array of those objects in the VBA environment.

The COM class in C# is done like that:

```
    [Guid("2e03fbca-d60a-44e8-893b-b619d653546c"), ComVisible(true)]
    public interface ICOMClass
    {
        int Property1 { get; set; }
        string Property2 { get; set; }
    }

    [Guid("733318f6-2d08-4824-936f-a0b9eafa3083"), ComVisible(true), ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
    public class COMClass : ICOMClass
        {
        public int Property1 { get; set; }
        public string Property2 { get; set; }

        public COMClass()
        {

        }

    }
```

The implementation in VBA is done like that:

```vb
'Object creation
Dim myCOMObject As New COMClass
myCOMObject.Property1 =20
myCOMObject.Property2 = "Cat"
'Creation is done correctly, now i want to add this object to an array

Dim myArrayOfComObject() As COMClass
ReDim myArrayOfComObject(10) As COMClass
myArrayOfComObject(1)=myCOMObject
```

I am able to create the single object but when trying to insert it in the array I get this error message:

> *(10094) ActiveX Automation: The variable Object is 'Nothing'*

If I look to the array I can see that all my objects are Nothing, I think I need to initialize them somehow but I don't know how.
Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: If I do like that I have an error on the line `Dim myArrayOfComObject() As New COMClass` that say: Expected a valid type (Ex. Integer)

Comment: How your class was referenced? I usually make that declaration type referring to classes made by me (in VBA...). Try modifying of only `ReDim myArrayOfComObject(10)`. without `As COMClass`.

Comment: There is function in the menu of the editor that do the reference at the COM component. I can see methods and write properties of single object correctly but when i create the arrays of an object defined in that class i got this problem

Comment: I am talking about referencing the class to the VBProject which must deal with it...

Comment: @FaneDuru No, you should not use the `New` keyword here. This is just an array, it has nothing to do with class instantiation. @Davide Benetti try `Set myArrayOfComObject(0)=myCOMObject` since you're dealing with an object.

Comment: Good to hear, I personally would go for a collection instead of redim-ing an array. Good luck.